# retrieve disk stats on command line

Tags: disk-usage, block-device

How can I most portably get disk stats from a bash script?

I am already using

```
cat /sys/block/*/stat
```

to calculate overall bandwidth by disk / partition, however I am trying to also determine the overall size of the disk, and number of sectors used / free.

I know that these stats are available using `df`, however I am looking for an alternative ( how does *df* do its backend work? ), preferable something that uses `/sys/class/` or `/sys/block/`.

Is this possible? Or would I need to use `df | awk` top get the stats I am looking for?

*edit*

Usecase:

This is for use in a metrics reporting script that will collect various bits of information from the system and report it to a graphing system.

i.e. grabbing sector read / write stats

```
for device in /sys/block/*
do

    stats=$( cat $device/stat )

    sectorsRead=$( echo $stats | awk '{print $3}' )
    sectorsWrite=$( echo $stats | awk '{print $7}' )

    doSomethingWith sectorsRead
    doSomethingWith sectorsWrite
done
```

I am looking to do something similar, but grab total number of sectors, vs sectors used / free.

Comment: Yes, I guessed as much or you wouldn't have posted here :) But *what* nix systems? The `/sys` directory is not standard. I think it's only Linux, but it certainly isn't [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html). I also expect it won't be present in most embedded systems. The `df` command, on the other hand *is* POSIX and will be present on any *nix system. So I'm trying to understand why you would want to avoid using the standard, portable tool and instead roll your own, less portable approach.

Comment: Fair enough - so my best bet would be looping the output of df, and awking through it? `mountPoint=$( df | awk '{print $5}' )`? Will the fields _always_ be the same?

Comment: Heh, no they won't. It's still probably the best tool for the job. Hang on, I'll write something up.

Comment: Aha, that was what I suspected, and why I was looking into `/sys` ;)

Comment: Please see the updated answer for an even more robustly portable approach (thanks to derobert).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most portable tool for what you are trying to do is `df`. Don't fiddle with `/sys` which is not guaranteed to be on any non-Linux system. And don't reinvent the wheel. This is precisely what `df` is for and why it is [specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html) by POSIX.

Of course, things aren't quite that simple and there are various `df` implementations, some of which have different formats. However, the good folks who write the POSIX specs have, in their infinite wisdom, included the following option in the specification of `df`:

```
 -P
    Produce output in the format described in the STDOUT section.
```

So, if you always use `df -P` that should be about as portable as it is possible to get. When using that flag, any POSIX-compliant `df` version (which should be all of them or as close as makes no difference) will produce oputput following the specification below (taken from the [POSIX `df` page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html)):

> When both the -k and -P options are specified, the following header
>   line shall be written (in the POSIX locale):
>
> "Filesystem 1024-blocks Used Available Capacity Mounted on\n"
>
> When the -P option is specified without the -k option, the following
>   header line shall be written (in the POSIX locale):
>
> "Filesystem 512-blocks Used Available Capacity Mounted on\n"
>
> The implementation may adjust the spacing of the header line and the
>   individual data lines so that the information is presented in orderly
>   columns.
>
> The remaining output with -P shall consist of one line of information
>   for each specified file system. These lines shall be formatted as
>   follows:
>
> "%s %d %d %d %d%% %s\n", , ,
>       , , ,
>
> In the following list, all quantities expressed in 512-byte units
>   (1024-byte when -k is specified) shall be rounded up to the next
>   higher unit. The fields are:
>
> The name of the file system, in an
>   implementation-defined format.  The total size of the
>   file system in 512-byte units. The exact meaning of this figure is
>   implementation-defined, but should include , ,
>   plus any space reserved by the system not normally available to a
>   user.  The total amount of space allocated to existing
>   files in the file system, in 512-byte units.  The total
>   amount of space available within the file system for the creation of
>   new files by unprivileged users, in 512-byte units. When this figure
>   is less than or equal to zero, it shall not be possible to create any
>   new files on the file system without first deleting others, unless the
>   process has appropriate privileges. The figure written may be less
>   than zero.  The percentage of the normally available
>   space that is currently allocated to all files on the file system.
>   This shall be calculated using the fraction: /( + )
>
> expressed as a percentage. This percentage may be greater than 100 if
>    is less than zero. The percentage value shall be
>   expressed as a positive integer, with any fractional result causing it
>   to be rounded to the next highest integer.
>
> The directory below which the file system hierarchy
>   appears.

You should probably also use the `-k` flag to always have the results printed as 1024-byte units instead of 512. And you may as well set `LC_ALL=POSIX` to make sure the locale won't affect the output.
Putting all that together gives:

Combining that with the also ultra-portable `awk`, you can do:

```
totalSectors=$(env -i LC_ALL=POSIX df -k -P /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR>1{print $2}')
usedSectors=$(env -i LC_ALL=POSIX df -k -P /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR>1{print $3}')
availableSectors=$(env -i LC_ALL=POSIX df -k -P /dev/sda1 | awk 'NR>1{print $4}')
```

Comment: Though here, `LC_ALL=POSIX df -P` (without `-k`) produces the `1024-blocks` header line. Same with even `env -i LC_ALL=POSIX df -P`. You need to also set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` with GNU Coreutils: `env -i LC_ALL=POSIX POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 df -P`

Comment: @derobert why? The header is part of the POSIX definition and I'm excluding it with the `NR>1` in awk.

Comment: Well, GNU Coreutils ignores the POSIX requirement—POSIX (as you quoted) says you should be getting sizes in 512-byte blocks, but coreutils thinks that's silly and gave you 1024-byte blocks instead. Your numbers will be off by a factor of 2.

Comment: (You could also of course use `df -P -k`, and then always have KiB everywhere. Which is probably a saner default, especially since it's not like disks have 512-byte sectors anymore)

Comment: @derobert yes, that seems far more reasonable. Thanks, again.